# 西海 vs 东海 in literature

Tags: culture, history, poetry, literature

In Chinese literature, poetry, song, etc. 西海 is used more often than  东海.  Is it because 西 in Chinese literature more romantic than 东?

For example if I compose a poem, would it be weird if I use 东海 instead?

Comment: 西海 is used more often than 东海? What proof do you have?

Comment: Please show examples of both in literature. Perhaps we can take it from there.

Comment: We still need to consider 北海 & 南海 as well? In English literature we have "Go East, Young Man", by William O. Douglas. And "Go West, Young Man", coined by Horace Greeley. So, it's 50-50?

Comment: take reference to _我居北海君南海_ I live in 北海(渤海) You live in 南海(廣州 四會) (寄黃幾復 •黃庭堅) or _君( you )處( stay in )北海，寡人( I )處( stay in )南海_

Comment: I don't think I have ever encountered 西海 in Chinese literature...

Comment: I take it back. I now remember seeing 西海龍王

Answer (score 0):

You must consider the geography of China. The majority of the population resides on the eastern side of the country, in an elongated region that stretches from north to south. The term '西海' is not commonly used, as there aren't many famous seas on the western side of China. For reference, the north, east, and south sides of China all have coastlines. Take, for example, the phrase '我居北海君南海'. Here, both '北海' and '南海' symbolize long distances rather than actual seas. Given the population distribution, the terms north and south are frequently used to indicate distance. As for the west, it's characterized more by deserts and exotic landscapes than by seas.